# Finding all cycles of length <=5 in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I was wondering if there's an efficient way to find all cycles of a graph of length <= 5 in a directed graph. I've read up on [Johnson's algorithm](https://blog.mister-muffin.de/2012/07/04/enumerating-elementary-circuits-of-a-directed_graph/) that takes `O((|V|+|E|)(c+1))` time to find all cycles of any length (where c is the total number of cycles), but that might be overkill considering I only need cycles of length at most 5. Is there a more efficient way to do this? The input graph can be pretty large with `|V| = 600` and Johnson's algorithm seems to take too long!

[A faster but approximate algorithm would do as well!]

P.S: I found [this StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877905/finding-all-cycles-in-directed-graphs-of-length-k) too, but the answer has 0 upvotes, so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/19508/5038, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3786/5038, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/33005/5038.

Comment: Working on your CS 170 final project?  Make sure to cite your sources, no matter what.  Also, I strongly encourage you to check with the instructors whether asking this kind of question is permissible -- are you sure whether that's allowed?   I wouldn't want to see anyone get in trouble over a misunderstanding...

Comment: "graph can be pretty large with |V| = 600" -- that's cute! "Large" means millions of nodes at least these days. A linear-time algorithm should be blazingly fast on graphs that size, provided you did not make mistakes.